# TypeError: defined function got an unexpected keyword argument 'many

Tags: python, python-3.x, marshmallow

I have a problem with my python app. I am following a tutorial posted on: https://auth0.com/blog/developing-restful-apis-with-python-and-flask/

I try to post data to the app by power-shell:

```
$params = @{amount=80; description='test_doc'}
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://127.0.0.1:5000/incomes -Method POST -Body ($params|ConvertTo-Json) -ContentType "application/json"
```

When i run the PS script i get an error from my python app:

```
TypeError: make_income() got an unexpected keyword argument 'many'
```

My code looks like this:

```
from marshmallow import post_load

from .transaction import Transaction, TransactionSchema
from .transaction_type import TransactionType


class Income(Transaction):
  def __init__(self, description, amount):
    super(Income, self).__init__(description, amount, TransactionType.INCOME)

  def __repr__(self):
    return '<Income(name={self.description!r})>'.format(self=self)


class IncomeSchema(TransactionSchema):
  @post_load
  def make_income(self, data):
    return Income(**data)
```

How am i getting the argument `many` into my function? Is this a marshmallow problem?

I have tried adding `**` but i get the same error:

```
 def make_income(self, **data):
    return Income(**data)
```

I have also tried

```
def make_income(self, data, **kwargs):
    return Income(**data)
```

Here is my transaction.py file

```
import datetime as dt

from marshmallow import Schema, fields


class Transaction():
  def __init__(self, description, amount, type):
    self.description = description
    self.amount = amount
    self.created_at = dt.datetime.now()
    self.type = type

  def __repr__(self):
    return '<Transaction(name={self.description!r})>'.format(self=self)


class TransactionSchema(Schema):
  description = fields.Str()
  amount = fields.Number()
  created_at = fields.Date()
  type = fields.Str()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In marsmallow 3, decorated methods (pre/post_dump/load,...) must swallow unknown kwargs.

```py
class IncomeSchema(TransactionSchema):
  @post_load
  def make_income(self, data, **kwargs):
    return Income(**data)
```

(You may want to notify the blog author about this.)

Comment: I have tried this and i am still getting the same error.

Comment: Please double-check the error message. I don't think you can get `make_income() got an unexpected keyword argument 'many'` with the correct signature `def make_income(self, data, **kwargs):`

Comment: Jérôme you were right. The problem was that i had:
  `def make_income(self, data):
    return Income(**data)` 
in two different files and i fixed it only in one of those files.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to accepted solution, please make the below changes:

```
@app.route('/incomes')
def get_incomes():
  schema = IncomeSchema(many=True)
  incomes = schema.dump(
    filter(lambda t: t.type == TransactionType.INCOME, transactions)
  )
  return jsonify(incomes.data) //change it to return jsonify(incomes)


@app.route('/incomes', methods=['POST'])
def add_income():
  income = IncomeSchema().load(request.get_json())
  transactions.append(income.data)//change it to transactions.append(income)
  return "", 204


@app.route('/expenses')
def get_expenses():
  schema = ExpenseSchema(many=True)
  expenses = schema.dump(
      filter(lambda t: t.type == TransactionType.EXPENSE, transactions)
  )
  return jsonify(expenses.data)// change it to return jsonify(expenses)


@app.route('/expenses', methods=['POST'])
def add_expense():
  expense = ExpenseSchema().load(request.get_json())
  transactions.append(expense.data) // change it to transactions.append(expense)
  return "", 204
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).